# how to deal with a foreign id that doesnt exist yet

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In my restaurant ordering website, my `orderitems` table has a foreign key which is the `order_id`. The problem is an order only exists after the user confirms their `orderitems` which means my `order_id` value will be referencing nothing until the order is recorded. I made a temporary fix but its very bad. How do i solve this?

my OrderitemController.php

```
public function storeOrderitem(Request $request, Menu $menu)
        $order_id = rand(1, 1000);

        $attributes = $request->validate([
            'quantity' => 'integer|min:1',
        ]); 

        $orderitem = new Orderitem;
        $orderitem->order_id = $order_id;
        $orderitem->menu_id = $menu->id;
        $orderitem->quantity = $attributes['quantity'];
        $orderitem->save();

        $orderitems = Orderitem::with('menu')->get();
        session(['orderitems' => $orderitems]);
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function show(Menu $menu)
    {
        return view('pages.order', [
            'menu' => $menu,
        ]);
    }
```

my MenuController.php

```
public function show(Menu $menu)//: Response
{
    //

    //dd($menu);
    $orderitems = session('orderitems');
    return view('pages/landing-page', [
        'menus' => Menu::latest()->get(),
        'orderitems' => $orderitems
    ]) ;
}
```

This is in my view, mainpage.blade.php

```
@foreach($orderitems as $orderitem)
      <li class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100">{{ $orderitem->menu->item_name }}<span class="ml-32">{{ $orderitem->menu->price }}</span></li>
@endforeach
```

If you need to see other files, just me let know

Comment: I'd say rethink the flow of this in Frontend. Make sure that the whole order is done before posting it so you can create the order and the items at the same time in backend.

Comment: You can pass the `$orderItem` to the session without saving it. the you can just save it after the order has been created.

Answer (score 0):

The question will be with out an order why you need to store order items?

So, I think Order and OrderItem model should get updated together, either you update order relationship after creating order or use a model observer to create OrderItems.

so in my prospective it will be assuming below is the structure of your models

```
Order
id
customer_id
created_at
updated_at
status
etc ....
```

and

```
OrderItem
id
product_id
order_id
quantity
price
etc..
```

order item will updated as soon as order will get created, to display in cart you can keep the selection in session itself or in cache or any temporary memory/database table which will get clean once it is cancelled or order fulfilled or with some time limit.